# Java data validation with while loops

Tags: java, validation

This applicaiton validates that the user is entering the correct data. I have about 95% of this done but I can not figure out the Continue? (y/n) part.  If you hit anything but y or n (or if you leave the line blank) it is supposed to print an error:So this is what the application is supposed to look like in the console:

Continue? (y/n):

Error! This entry is required. Try again.

Continue? (y/n): x

Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again.

Continue? (y/n): n

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("Welcome to the Loan Calculator");
   System.out.println();

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String choice = "y";
   while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
   {
       System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
       double loanAmount = getDoubleWithinRange(sc, "Enter loan amount: ", 0, 1000000);
       double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc, "Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 20);
       int years = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);

       double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate/12/100;
       int months = years * 12; 
       double monthlyPayment = calculateMonthlyPayment(loanAmount, monthlyInterestRate, months);


       NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
       NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
       percent.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

       String results = "Loan amount: \t\t" + currency.format(loanAmount) + "\n"
               + "Yearly interest rate: \t" + percent.format(interestRate/100) + "\n"
               + "Number of years: \t" + years + "\n"
               + "Monthly payment: \t" + currency.format(monthlyPayment) + "\n";

       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("FORMATTED RESULTS");
       System.out.println(results);

      String getContinue = getContinueWithinRange(sc, "Continue? (y/n): ", "y", "n");
      System.out.print(getContinue);
      System.out.println();
   }

}
public static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, double min, double max)
{
    double d = 0.0;
    boolean isValid = false; 
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
        if (d <=min) {
            System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        }
        else if (d >= max) {
            System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
        }
        else {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return d; 
}
public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    double d = 0.0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextDouble())
        {
            d = sc.nextDouble();
                    isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid decimal value. Try Again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    return d; 
}
public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, int min, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        i = getInt(sc, prompt);
        if (i <= min) {
            System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        }
        else if (i >= max) {
            System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
        }
        else {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return i; 
}
public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if(sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            isValid = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    return i;

}
public static double calculateMonthlyPayment(double loanAmount, double monthlyInterestRate, double months)
{
    double monthlyPayment = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
    {
        monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate/(1 - 1/Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, months));
    }
    return monthlyPayment;
}
      System.out.print(getContinue);
      System.out.println();        
public static String getContinueWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, String yContinue, String nContinue)
{ 
String i = ""; 
boolean isValid = false;
while (isValid == false)
{
       i = getContinue(sc, prompt);
       if (!yContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !nContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
           System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again.");
       }        
       else{
           isValid = true;
       }
}
return i;
 }
public static String getContinue(Scanner sc, String prompt)
 {
 String i = "";
 boolean isValid = false;
 while(isValid == false)
 {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (i.length() > 0)
        {

            i = sc.nextLine(); 
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Entry is required. Try again.");
        }       
        sc.nextLine();
 }
 return i;
}
}
```

Comment: In the loop in getContinue(), you start off with the empty string that has length 0; thats why you always get the error initially. In getContinueWithinRange, you never assign yContinue or nContinue, so you always compare "y" and "n" against "" which will always give back false, so the condition is always true.

Comment: On another note: the title of your question has nothing to do with your problem; try to phrase your questions more succinctly in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Sorry you're right at first I was going to post the main method too, but I'm really only having problems with the two String methods above.  I should have changed the title.  So, how should I assign yContinue and nContinue?  Also, would it help if I posted the main method?

Comment: Please post the complete code that compiles.

Comment: My comment was badly phrased, ill post an answer shortly.

Comment: okay the entire code has been added

Comment: What does your program do when you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the content of the while loop in getContinue() to this:

```
System.out.print(prompt);
i = sc.nextLine();
if (i.length() > 0)
{
    isValid = true;
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Error! Entry is required. Try again.");
}
```

This first prints the prompt, then reads the input into the variable that will be returned, then checks whether the input had length greater than zero.

---

In getContinueWithinRange(), the condition in the if clause needs to be replaced by

```
!yContinue.equalsIgnoreCase(i) && !nContinue.equalsIgnoreCase(i)
```

This will "y" and "n" against the input instead of against "".

---

Also if you would like to actually continue after reading a "y", you need to do something like this:

```
if (!yContinue.equalsIgnoreCase(i) && !nContinue.equalsIgnoreCase(i)){
    System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again.");
}        
else {
    isValid = true;
}
```

The first case catches invalid input, the second ends the loop if the user entered "n", the third tells the user the loop will continue after he entered a "y".

---

Finally, to make your program do what it's supposed to do, change

```
String getContinue = getContinueWithinRange(sc, "Continue? (y/n): ", "y", "n");
```

to

```
choice = getContinueWithinRange(sc, "Continue? (y/n): ", "y", "n");
```

in your main method.

Comment: I tried this code and it does fix the loops. Somehow you didn't call the methods correctly in the rest of your code though.

Comment: This did not work for me.  When y is entered it is supposed to bring the user back to the top to DATA ENTRY and when n is entered the program should end.

Comment: Like i said, you didnt tie your methods into the rest of your code correctly. See my answer again, i edited it.

Comment: Would this work?    String getContinue = getContinueWithinRange(sc, "Continue? (y/n): ", "y", "n");
          choice = getContinue;

Comment: Yes that would work as well, but it's redundant. Make sure to also reread the third paragraph of my answer, the while loop wasn't used the way i expected so it had to be changed again.

Answer (score 1):

I try something for you according to your first submitted code

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Tester4 {

    public static String getContinueWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, String yContinue, String nContinue) {
        String result = "";
        boolean isValid = false;
        boolean isStarted = false;
        while(!isValid) {
            result = getContinue(sc, prompt, isStarted);
            isStarted = true;
            if(yContinue.equalsIgnoreCase(result) || nContinue.equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                isValid = true;
            } else if(!yContinue.equalsIgnoreCase(result) || !nContinue.equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again.");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getContinue(Scanner sc, String prompt, boolean isStarted) {
        String result = "";
        boolean isValid = false;
        while(!isValid) {
            if(result.isEmpty() && !isStarted) {
                System.out.print(prompt);
                System.out.println("Error! Entry is required. Try again.");
            }
            result = sc.nextLine();
            if(result.length() > 0) {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String getContinue = getContinueWithinRange(sc, "Continue? (y/n): ", "y", "n");
        // to call the method
        System.out.print(getContinue);
        System.out.println();
    }

    // InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg");
    // BufferedImage bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(stream);
    // ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class LoanPaymentApp {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Loan Calculator");
    System.out.println();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
    {
   System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
   double loanAmount = getDoubleWithinRange(sc, "Enter loan amount: ", 0, 1000000);
   double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc, "Enter yearly interest       rate: ", 0, 20);
   int years = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);

   double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate/12/100;
   int months = years * 12; 
   double monthlyPayment = calculateMonthlyPayment(loanAmount, monthlyInterestRate, months);


   NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
   NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
   percent.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

   String results = "Loan amount: \t\t" + currency.format(loanAmount) + "\n"
           + "Yearly interest rate: \t" + percent.format(interestRate/100) + "\n"
           + "Number of years: \t" + years + "\n"
           + "Monthly payment: \t" + currency.format(monthlyPayment) + "\n";

   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("FORMATTED RESULTS");
   System.out.println(results);


   System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
             if (choice.equals(""))
             {
                System.out.println("Error! This entry is required. Try again.");
                System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
             }
             else
             {
                  System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again.");
                  System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
             }
            choice = sc.nextLine();
        }

        }

        }
        public static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, double min, double max)
{
double d = 0.0;
boolean isValid = false; 
while (isValid == false)
{
    d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
    if (d <=min) {
        System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
    }
    else if (d >= max) {
        System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
    }
    else {
        isValid = true;
    }
}
return d; 
}
public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
double d = 0.0;
boolean isValid = false;
while (isValid == false)
{
    System.out.print(prompt);
    if (sc.hasNextDouble())
    {
        d = sc.nextDouble();
                isValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid decimal value. Try Again.");
    }
    sc.nextLine();
}
 return d; 
}
public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, int min, int max)
{
int i = 0;
boolean isValid = false;
while (isValid == false)
{
    i = getInt(sc, prompt);
    if (i <= min) {
        System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
    }
    else if (i >= max) {
        System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
    }
    else {
        isValid = true;
    }
}
return i; 
}
public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
int i = 0;
boolean isValid = false;
while (isValid == false)
{
    System.out.print(prompt);
    if(sc.hasNextInt())
    {
        i = sc.nextInt();
        isValid = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
    }
    sc.nextLine();
}
return i;

}
 public static double calculateMonthlyPayment(double loanAmount, double monthlyInterestRate, double months)
 {
double monthlyPayment = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
{
    monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate/(1 - 1/Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, months));
}
return monthlyPayment;
}

}
```

Comment: You should explain your code, in English, so it is simpler to understand your answer.